# По поводу названия буквы Х и неприличного слова

Tags: этимология, этикет, обсценная-лексика

Прочитал тут, что слово (заранее прошу пардону) "похерить" происходит вовсе не от известного ругательства, а от старого названия буквы Х. То есть, поставить на чем-то крест.
Выходит, слово "похерить", то есть, испортить что-то — вовсе не неприличное и его можно употреблять?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

О происхождении - да. Именно от названия буквы..
Что касается табуированности, то вопрос весьма неоднозначный. 
Она определяется не происхождением, а современным отношением к тому или иному слову.

*Примечательна история цепочки "уд-х@й-хер-член" в которой каждое последующее слово изобреталось или выбиралось для использования как замена табуированным предыдущим, но постепенно само становилось в той или иной степени табуированным. Кажется, даже, там ещё звенья были, но менее известные.*

[Список матных слов 30 шт | newforum.gramota.ru](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=22&start=40)
(Простите за самоцитирование)

Нечто подобное, кстати, скоро произойдет по понятным причинам с глаголам "трахать".

Comment: И уже почти произошло с совершенно невинным глаголом "кончить". 
И почему это носителям языка хочется табуировать как можно больше слов? 

Кстати, в вашей цепочке наиболее "неприличным" является второе слово, вы даже не стали его "писать, как произносится". А вот первое уже потеряло неприличную окраску, выглядит скорее архаизмом (большинство населения его вообще не знает). Так что, вполне возможно, в будущем "неприличность" будет перемещаться слева направо :)  
Тем более, что традиционные матерные слова уже стали практически обычными в речи громадной доли населения.

Comment: >Так что, вполне возможно, в будущем "неприличность" будет перемещаться слева направо  
  
Именно так. Я это уже говорил, кажется в той же дискуссии по ссылке.
Ну может, еще где-то. 
Я "не стал писать" уважая труд модератора, который, как знаю по опыту, может и не понять.  
//===================  
Так вот, в 50-х годах, в киевском, если не ошибаюсь издательстве, готовился к печати большой китайско-русский словарь. Какой-то начальствующий борец за нравственность повелел наборщикам везде заменить транскрипцию ХУЙ (т.е. едва ли не на каждой странице) на многоточие.

Comment: Хватились не сразу, большая часть набора была уже готова, сроки поджимали, а что такое типографский набор иероглифов в те времена - лучше к ночи не вспоминать. Словарь, однако, вышел в срок, весь тираж был сметен с полок мгновенно, и до сих пор истинные ценители готовы выложить бешенные бабки за этот раритет. Для тех, кто не догадался. Словарь вышел с многоточиями, но в списке замеченных опечаток на первом месте стояло ",,, - читать ХУЙ".

Comment: Слово "похерить" есть у Набокова в "Лолите"

Comment: У Даля есть ПОХЕРИТЬ, выхерить или помарать, вычеркнуть. Эту штука (или шутка) стара: похерить пора.

Comment: Не только в "Лолите" (кое произведение образцом для воспитания нравственности вообще вряд ли может служить), но и в "Вассе Железновой".

Answer (score 0):

Корень *яр*, он же *гер*, он же *хер* означает нечто неудержимо поднимающееся: Ярило (весенне солнце), яро (весна), ярость. Однокоренными являются *Германия* и немецкое обращение Herr(господин).

Что касается глагола *похерить*. В славянской азбуке существовала буква *хер*, которая писалась в форме креста. *Похерить* - перечеркнуть крестом.

Answer (score -1):

```
   С искренним -  
                         Б.А.
```

Comment: Потому что у большинства с мозгами в порядке.  
Кстати, я читала где-то, что название "хер" - сокращение от слова "херувим".

Comment: "Миллиарды людей наравне с русским знают ..." И сколько, примерно, миллиардов? Гдэ-нибуд 7-8?

Comment: >Кстати, я читала где-то, что название "хер" - сокращение от слова "херувим".  
Не совсем так. Когда исходное "хер" стало приобретать неприличную  приобретать неприличную окраску, "во избежание" и была придумана эта история про сокращение: букву "в дамском варианте" стали называть "херувим".

Comment: Прежде всего, Ирина-"Docentl": ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ!

Вы, конечно, понимаете, что я тоже мог бы ответить Вам колкостью на колкость. Но этот сайт, как мы видим, создавался не для взаимных оскорблений, а для ответов на вопросы людей о происхождении слов и выражений нашего языка, не так ли?!
А вот по теме перевода слова “херувим”, наоборот, – отвечу.
Если бы мы отталкивались от четырёхтомной компиляции Фасмера, то пришлось бы нам согласиться на том, что Бог поставил охранять Рай “какого-то хера”.  (Мильпардон, конечно, но мы разбираем слово.) Прямо как Морской царь – двух осетров в неприличной, но
.

Comment: неприличной, но весёлой подростковой песенке про Садко. (Что, в общем-то, тоже недалеко от истинной картины, как мы помним из “Библии”.)
На самом же деле “херувим” (бригский “кырубим”) – от древнерусского слова “корова”, “коровин” (т.е. понятно: “коровин” – это “слуга Тельца”), которое переврали вездесущие гэлы. Потому что они в родительном и звательном падеже произносили его как “хáравин” (ср.: Кáлум – Хáлум (а Хáлум), кóман – хóман, кóнай – хóнай)).  Их и изображали-то частенько именно в виде быков с умозрительными крылышками.
.

Comment: (Не гэлов изображали в виде быков с крылышками, а херувимов, конечно, так изображали.) Более подробно об этом см. по приведённому мной адресу.

                                                        Б. Александров

P.S. Кстати, – “Харбин” тоже означает “Коровий город”. Дальневосточный Туров.
.

Comment: Я не настаиваю на "херувиме", но объяснение @behemothus мне нравится больше. А ваше - никуда не годится.  
Я не навешиваю ярлыки, просто режу правду-матку. Такие измышления по внешнему сходству стали сейчас популярны у некоторой (не весьма грамотной) части публики. Но толку в них нет никакого.

Comment: Поражает даже не дремучая невежественность таких авторов 1)  а то, насколько назойливо они продвигают свои версии.

Впрочем, одно вытекает из другого.


1) *Типа сноска. Ручаюсь, что данный товарищ не имеет ни малейшего представления о фонетике гэльского, которая, кстати, сильно изменилась с того момента, когда было возможно прямое заимствование оттуда во французский).