# Имеет ли слово "похерить" грубый оттенок в современном русском языке?

Tags: лексика

По данной теме нашла только вот это обсуждение: [По поводу названия буквы Х и неприличного слова](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/23279/177015).

Подскажите, каков статус этого глагола в современном русском языке? Можно ли употреблять его, к примеру, в деловом общении в смысле "зачеркнуть", "убрать"?

Я встречала людей (образованных и мною глубоко уважаемых), которые использовали слово "похерить" в его исконном смысле - "убрать", "зачеркнуть", безо всякого намека на что-то грубое. Но недавно была неприятно поражена тем фактом, что многие сейчас считают это слово чуть ли не матерным и совершенно неприемлемым.

Comment: Времена  меняются  -  и  мы  меняемся  вместе  с  ними.

Answer (score 7):

Тут примерно та же история, что и со словом "кончить". Старшее поколение свободно употребляет это слово в его исходном смысле, а более молодые почти наверняка добавят приставку "за-", чтобы избежать двусмысленности. Правда если с "кончить" возрастная граница употребления лежит, примерно, в промежутке около 30-40 лет, то с "похерить", по моим субъективным оценкам, разделение смыслов между поколениями произошло раньше. Скажем я, вряд ли бы стал употреблять данное слово вне мужской компании, использовав при необходимости синонимы "перечеркнуть" или "зачеркнуть".

В целом, "похерить" формально не мат и даже эвфемизмом его назвать нельзя (нет матерного аналога), но так как сейчас у многих людей оно будет восприниматься как слово пониженной лексики (и причина тут скорее не культурном уровне, а в возрасте), я бы не рекомендовал использовать его в деловом общении.

Answer (score 4):

Не думаю, что многие, только те, чей интеллект невысок и словарь приближен к ЭЛЛОЧКЕ Ильфа и Петрова. В современной лексике статус этого слова — устаревшее и просторечное со значением "ликвидировать, уничтожить"(Ожегов).

А грубый эвфемизм — существительное, на который Вам намекнули, остаётся неприличным, хотя и не матерным, слово вобрало в себя неприличный смысл другого, которое заменило, оно как бы расслоилось на грязное новое и чистое старое. Сегодня такой же процессс происходит со словом "хрен", но у него хотя бы основное значение не выходит из употребления, не устаревает. Однако глагола от этого эвфемизма нет, поэтому дурные ассоциации только у тех, кто не обладает знанием истории, языка и общей культурой.

Как быть — другой вопрос: нужно знать, при ком можно употребить устаревшее слово, а при ком можно говорить на ЕГО языке, чтоб он понял.

Comment: А под "деловым общением" Вы что подразумеваете? Если письменное - то в деловом письме странно будет звучать такой архаизм:"Похерьте все предыдущие документы". А в устной речи деловых людей как раз приемлемо и будет говорить о достаточно высокой культуре :"Да всё это уже давно похерили, всё ушло в давность"

Answer (score 2):

Херъ - Буква в Азбуке и ничего отрицательного не несёт.

Херъ - имеет значение условного знака в виде креста. Ср. в межевой грамоте начала XVI в.: «а на пеньѣ признака два хера на крестѣ» (Обнорский, с. 35). Отсюда и возникает глагол херить (ср. захерить, похерить) с значением: «уничтожать или отмечать что-нибудь... изображением креста или хера, перечеркивать, зачеркивать» (см. сл. 1867—1868, 4, с. 874).

Ср. в «Соборянах» Н. С. Лескова (в речи дьякона Ахиллы): «...Владыка решение консисторское о назначении следствия насчет проповеди синим хером перечеркнули и все тем негласно успокоили, что назначили отца Савелия к причетнической при архиерейском доме должности» (1957, 4, с. 239—240). Понятно, что в «Материалах» Срезневского глагола хѣрити не указано.

По-видимому, как канцелярски-деловые слова глаголы херить и похерить имели широкое хождение в русском языке XVII—XVIII в. Ср. в словарях Академии Российской: «Похерить — вымарать, исключить что из написанного. Похерить имя чье в списке» (ч. 5, с. 103). Но в средний стиль художественной литературы эти выражения не входили.

Из значения— «зачеркивать — перечеркивать, отмечать знаком креста наподобие буквы X» — в глаголе херить — (при форме сов. вида похерить) легко развивается оттенок: «уничтожать, ликвидировать». Это расширение объема значения слова херить — похерить наметилось в разговорно-чиновничьем, служилом диалекте — еще давно — не позднее XVIII в. Но этот оттенок значения особенно резко выступил в русском литературном языке с 30—40 гг. XIX в., когда слово похерить было допущено и в стили художественно-повествовательной литературы. У И. С. Тургенева в повести «Клара Милич»: «Наконец, это ему все надоело — и он решился, как говорится, ”взять на себя“ и похерить всю эту историю, так как она несомненно мешала его занятиям и нарушала его покой» (гл. 8). У Н. С. Лескова в очерке «В Москве»: «Какая свиньища однако же этот Розанов: его тоже непременно нужно будет похерить».

У А. Толстого в «Дон-Жуане» (в речи Сатаны):

Беда все отрицать! В иное надо верить,

Не то пришлось бы, чорт возьми,

Мне самого себя похерить!

Answer (score 0):

Глагол *похерить* в современном русском языке является изысканно-литературным, он придает оттенок старомодной стилизации авторскому тексту.

> Василий Аксенов. Остров Крым (авторская редакция) (1977-1979)
> Цэрэушники, что ли, перекупили? **Похерил он свою Идею Общей Судьбы?** Марлен Михайлович спокойно взял в руки увесистый «Курьер» (откровенно говоря, обожал он этот печатный орган, души в нем не чаял), быстро прошелестел страницами...

В устном общении слово может легко применяться, если собеседники хорошо знакомы, знают речевые особенности друг друга и тд. Вообще, среди людей, постоянно работающих с документами, сабж является жаргонным термином, который сохраняется с давних канцелярских времен. Зачеркнул = похерил.

> — Тьфу! Ты, кочерыжка, меня запутала! Не померла еще, так и говори, что не померла, а нечего в за упокой лезть! Путаешь тут! **Изволь вот теперь Федосью херить** и в другое место писать... всю бумагу изгадил! Ну, слушай, я тебе прочту...

Answer (score 0):

Мне по большому счету добавить к сказанному по Вашей ссылке нечего.
Слово заведомо не относится к т.н. матерной лексике, и, скорее всего, не является табуированным или нецензурным ни в каком смысле. Но это еще не означает возможность и приемлемость употребления во всех случаях. Уважайте, по возможности, понимание собеседника.

Чтобы хоть что-то сказать, поведаю, что при использовании разных вполне, казалось бы, невинных слов и оборотов, неоднократно сталкивался с поистине анекдотическим отношением...
Скажем, "быть на подхвате" в определенной среде было воспринято как сравнение с... гм...  ассенизатором. Причин такого отношения я до сих пор не знаю. Возможно какой-то профессионализм.

Короче, не говорите о веревке в доме повешенного - и да будет Вам "щщасте".

Comment: Ну... если следовать Вашей логике, то в некоторых классах (как-то,  видимо, подбираются дети из особых  семей) я не должна употреблять слова авторитет, голубой, кончить, спускать, члены, петух, опустить... Можно продолжать долго. И не только  употреблять  не должна, но и  тексты учебные вычитывать. Да у меня фантазии не хватит додумывать, какое слово может иметь другое, не слишком приличное с их точки зрения, значение. А со словом "похерить" надо, кстати, как-нибудь детей познакомить, чтобы не думали, что это нечто неприличное.

Comment: Гм... вопрос, конечно, интересный... Моя логика так далеко не распространяется. Тем более, что я слаб в педагогике. Но если в двух словах - нет, конечно. Вы же преподаете не "предмет русский язык", а русский язык как таковой. Ваша речь служит не просто коммуникативным средством (как в случаях, о которых я говорил), но и образцом для подражания.  
  
С другой стороны, рекомендовать совсем уж не учитывать подобные подводные камни я бы поостерегся. Ведь этак можно и урок совать. Если знаете заранее, где можно соломки постелить, почему бы это и не сделать?

Comment: Хотя тут вообще-то надо с каждым словом конкретно разбираться. "кончить", например, на мой вкус явно уступает по стилистике синонимичному "закончить", так что тут дело не только в двойном смысле.

Comment: Это от смысла зависит. Да, конечно, ребятам на уроке я говорю "Заканчиваем работу"  Но в значении "прекращай" все-таки уместнее  "кончай работу". (Почему-то представляется лес и крик одного лесоруба другим:"Кончай работу!" Может, фильм такой был?)